# Monoid mempty in pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, monoids

I tried to write a generalized `maximum` function similar to the one in `Prelude`. My first naiv approach looked like this:
`maximum' :: (F.Foldable a, Ord b) => a b -> Maybe b`
`maximum' mempty = Nothing`
`maximum' xs = Just $ F.foldl1 max xs`

However, when I test it it always returns `Nothing` regardless of the input:
`> maximum' [1,2,3]`
`> Nothing`

Now I wonder whether it's possible to obtain the empty value of a Monoid type instance. A test function I wrote works correctly:
`getMempty :: (Monoid a) => a -> a`
`getMempty _ = mempty`

`> getMempty [1,2,3]`
`> []`

I had already a look at these two questions but I didn't figure out how the answers solve my problem:
[Write a Maximum Monoid using Maybe in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344164/write-a-maximum-monoid-using-maybe-in-haskell)
[Haskell Pattern Matching on the Empty Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327532/haskell-pattern-matching-on-the-empty-set)

How would I rewrite the `maximum'` function to get it to work ?

Comment: Your first approach fails because you can't pattern match on arbitrary values, only constructors. You're binding the argument to a variable named `mempty`, which shadows the one defined in `Monoid`. The second question you linked touches on similar issues. How best to accomplish your actual goal is a different matter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As C. A. McCann points out in his comment, you can't pattern match on values, only patterns.

The equation `maximum' mempty = Nothing` is actually equivalent to the equation `maximum' x = Nothing`. The argument gets bound to a name and `Nothing` is returned.

Here's a way to make your code work:

```
maximum' :: (F.Foldable a, Ord b, Eq (a b), Monoid (a b)) => a b -> Maybe b
maximum' xs
  | xs == mempty = Nothing
  | otherwise    = Just $ F.foldl1 max xs
```

I.e. you can *compare* the value `xs` against `mempty`. Note that we need a `Monoid` constraint to be able to get at the value `mempty :: a b` and an `Eq` constraint to be able to compare as well.

An other, more elegant, solution would be to use a fold to differentiate between the empty and non-empty cases:

```
maximum'' :: (F.Foldable a, Ord b) => a b -> Maybe b
maximum'' xs = F.foldl max' Nothing xs
  where max' Nothing x = Just x
        max' (Just y) x = Just $ max x y
```

Comment: You can pattern match on literals, which are values rather than patterns.

Comment: Actually, literals are patterns. See for example the grammar in section 3.17.1 in the haskell report: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html

Comment: @MrBones: Literal "patterns" are syntactic sugar defined by translation to guards and equality checks, as you will discover if you attempt to match literals with a `Num` instance but no `Eq` instance. There's no *inherent* reason the same translation couldn't be used for things like `mempty` as well, just the matter of distinguishing such pseudo-patterns from bindings that shadow existing identifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had the same idea after C. A. McCann pointed out the shadowing of `Data.Monoid.mempty`.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do this (the one @opqdonut demonstrates is good). One could also make a "maximum" monoid around `Maybe`, and use `foldMap`.

```
newtype Maximum a = Max { unMaximum :: Maybe a }

instance (Ord a) => Monoid (Maximum a) where
  mempty = Max Nothing
  mappend (Max Nothing) b = b
  mappend a (Max Nothing) = a
  mappend (Max (Just a)) (Max (Just b)) = Max . Just $ (max a b)

maximum' = unMaximum . F.foldMap (Max . Just)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways, one is (as you mention) to create an instance of `Monoid`. However, we need to wrap it to `Maybe` to distinguish the case when we have no values. The implementation might look like this:

```
import Data.Monoid (Monoid, mempty, mappend)
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

-- Either we have a maximum value, or Nothing, if the
-- set of values is empty.
newtype Maximum a = Maximum { getMaximum :: Maybe a }
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

instance Ord a => Monoid (Maximum a) where
    mempty                      = Maximum Nothing

    -- If one part is Nothing, just take the other one.
    -- If both have a value, take their maximum.
    (Maximum Nothing) `mappend` y    = y
    x `mappend` (Maximum Nothing)    = x
    (Maximum (Just x)) `mappend` (Maximum (Just y))
                                     = Maximum (Just $ x `max` y)


maximum' :: (F.Foldable t, Ord a) => t a -> Maximum a
maximum' = F.foldMap (Maximum . Just)
```

Comment: Hahaha, we posted almost identical answers at almost exactly the same time! +1

Answer (score 2):

As many have already told you, you can't pattern match on a value.

As fewer people have told you, pattern matching is arguably the Haskell equivalent of object fields in a language like Java: it's valuable for internal consumption by tightly coupled code, but probably not something you wish to expose to external client code.  Basically, if you let a piece of code know your type's constructors, now you can never change these constructors without changing that other piece of code—even if your type's semantics did not really change.

The best solution here is really to just use `Foldable.foldr`:

```
maximum' :: (F.Foldable a, Ord b) => a b -> Maybe b
maximum' = F.foldr step Nothing
    where step x Nothing = Just x
          step x (Just y) = Just (max x y)
```

Note that `foldr` is a generalized *destructor* or *eliminator* for `Foldable` instances: its two arguments are "what to do with a non-empty `Foldable`" and "what to do with `mempty`.  This is more abstract and reusable than pattern matching.

Comment: On the other hand, if your type's semantics *did* change, breaking that other code is a *very good thing*--and in an ideal world, a type's representation would coincide with the semantics, as with `[]` or `Maybe`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
maximum' :: (Monoid (t a), F.Foldable t, Ord a, Eq (t a)) => t a -> Maybe a
maximum' xs
   | xs == mempty = Nothing
   | otherwise    = Just $ F.foldl1 max xs
```

You were missing a guard.

On the `getEmpty` function, you don't need it. Just use `mempty`, and allow its type to be inferred.

Comment: I think this also requires an `Eq (a b)` constraint, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, when I actually tried this, the inferred type signature was different. I'll change it in a sec